# IntelliJ IDEA 12: settings/deployment deploys to src/main/webapp instead of /?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 12 has a setting called "Deployment" which hot deploys updated files to the exploded folder either by request or automatically. Except it copies /src/main/webapp/index.html to [specified deployment folder]/src/main/webapp/index.html. How can I get it to copy from /src/main/webapp into the specified deployment folder without preserving source code folder structure?

Comment: Try to create a new exploded artifact manually. I'd still recommend to report it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA and provide a sample project that will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this could help you.

Go to:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Chose your web module -> Chose Web facet in your module -> Edit your Web resource directories.
```

[image]

Comment: I have that, Web Resource directory is "C:\work\trunk\projects\config\src\main\webapp" and Path Relative to Deployment Root is "/" and still index.html from src/main/webapp goes not to deployment root but to <deployment root>/src/main/webapp.. Idea 12 has just been released, may be a bug?

Comment: Do you have pure JEE web module or do you add some other frameworks? Like GWT. Maybe your framework generates this folders to your webapp. Other ways you can create issue in IDEA youtracker.

Comment: It's pure and simple standard maven web app.. I'll just install auto-package plugin, worked fine for previous itellij..

Comment: If everything was ok in previous version and now it's not working in idea 12. You should rise question in jetbrains youtrack.